# Can ctrlp work in white list mode?

Tags: plugin-ctrlp

Ctrlp provides a way to ignore some files or folders:

```
" ctrlp configuraation
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
   \ 'dir': '\v[\/](\.git|\.sql|\.hg|\.svn|vendor|var|sass|bin|app|web)$',
   \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll)$',
   \ 'doc': '\v\.(md|rst)$',
   \ }
```

As you can see, there is a `vendor` folder in my ignore list. I usually keep it out from ctrlp because makes it really slow down the plugin.

Nonetheless, I need to add just two or three folders contained in the `vendor` one. Can I configure ctrlp to exclude all folders inside vendor, but accept (for example) `Symfony` and `Doctrine`?

Comment: I've not found anything related to that, so here's an alternate idea. If you use a git repository, you can configure the .gitignore file to do that.

Comment: But I need ctrlp configuration issue, ... what does git configuration can help???

Comment: You can use git's file searcher as your ctrlp command. Thus, this will take the gitignore into account.

Comment: But I do not want that ctrlp ignore all git's ignored files. For example, I need that ctrlp indexes also vendor folder, but only few folders inside it.

Comment: Yes, but as I said previously, I don't think it's possible with just ctrlp (but I may be wrong), I'm just suggesting another way to do this which should work.